# Problem with calling javascript from angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to call javascript function from the typescript function.
This is not working at all.

I have created sudo code in stackblitz. Please check the same.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nullyo

Comment: Maybe you should clarify that you're trying to import the `hello()` for an external script `"src/external/sample.js"`...

Comment: This may be an issue with Stackblitz (the scripts in the angular.json specifically) as your example works in a local new project. If you put a `console.log(...)` statement in the `sample.js` file outside of that function to ensure it gets loaded, it never gets called in Stackblitz.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I think that too. But as per stavam 's answer if we export it that works well. I am not sure how export actually works with stackblitz or this is the alwasys case we should mention export for each function in javascript.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export it at one place, import it at another.

**hello.js**

```
export function hello() {
  console.log('hello world');
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { hello } from '../external/hello.js';

@Component({
  // ...
})
export class AppComponent  {   
  buttonClick() {
    console.log('btn click called. 1.');
    hello();
    console.log('btn click called. 2.');
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h1xqau?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Why it is working locally but not in stackblitz? I mean it is every time need to import and not just declaring it in package.jso

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have one sequential problem for which I have actually created stackblitz sudo and came across this problem. Please check this if it is the proper way to perform scenario [link][1]. [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55683030/typescript-to-javascript-call-back-function-can-not-access-typescript-global-var