# typescript to javascript call back function can not access typescript global variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback, scope

I can not access typescript global variable from javascript call of callback function passed of same typescript method.

Here is an example code in stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quhktp

In example above incr variable which is declared in component file. Can be accessed in clickthisfunction method when we directly use it. But if the same method passed to javascript for a call back. call back function is called but this method couldn't access this.incr variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functions in javascript, `this` refers to the object on which the function was called.
So if you call `this.clickthisfunction()`, `this.incr` works fine, but if you reassign `this.clickthisfunction` to some other variable, the `this` in that function won't be what you expect. This [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) has more information about how `this` works.

To fix this, there are a few options:

---

**bind**:

You can change what the `this` value in a function will be by calling `.bind` on it.
You can do this in the `constructor` by adding this line:

```js
this.clickthisfunction = this.clickthisfunction.bind(this);
```

You can also bind it right before you pass it to `withargumentcallwithfunctionasargument`,
but binding isn't free, so it's more typical to only do it once.

---

**Arrow functions**:

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) handle `this` differently – they capture it from the outer scope instead of using the object the function was called on.

By replacing the function declaration with this

```js
clickthisfunction = () => {
```

it will capture the `this` value from when the object is constructed.
(If you are interested how it's getting the this value, look at the transpiled code,
it makes a lot more sense).

---

Either one of these should fix `this` being undefined, and which you use is mostly a matter of style. The only difference is that the first approach will leave a function on the prototype, while the second will only have the function on the instances. That probably won't affect anything, though, unless you do something strange.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas understood this concept. I used arrow function which resolved my query.

Answer (score 0):

One little mistake there. You need to call it when you pass it.

This should do the trick:

```
  clickthisargwithfunction() {
    withargumentcallwithfunctionasargument(this.clickthisfunction());
  }
```

Comment: No this is not the case. I am not trying to call a function and put returned value as an argument. Instead I am trying to pass a function in javascript as a callback function.

Comment: So the error when you try to click on the button that calls the fn as a callback is unintentional?